# cellForRowAtIndexPath is not be called

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a viewcontroller called `BNRItemViewcontroller`

In the implementation:

```
- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]createItem];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style{
    return [self init];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count];
}
```

I add a breakpoint in the **cellForRowAtIndexPath:** method,but it didn't get in the method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    BNRItem *item = items[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item description];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Is `[[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count]` non-zero?  Did you set the tableview data source?

Comment: Is `numberOfRowsInSection` called? If yes, make sure it is not returning 0. If it is not called , make sure you have set delegate and data source properly, as mentioned in above comments

Comment: yes,`[[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count] ` equals to 0

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and it is returning 0

Comment: Ok, thats the reason `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isnt called, you need to check your logic and find out why the array count is 0.

Comment: I find out the logic problem of my code,and I edit it and  `numberOfRowsInSection`is called and returns 5,however, the new problem    appears, the  debug area shows this information`2016-07-25 15:11:17.348 Homepwner[19994:400896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier UITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
`

Comment: And I didn't use the Storyboard or xib

Comment: I will help you can you please send me your code?

Comment: It's done,thank you.

Comment: I use the reusablecell method and I didn't register the cell.And if I manually create the cell I don't have to register the cell class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have followed these steps:

**Step 1:** Conform to `UITableViewDataSourceDelegate` and `UITableViewDelegate`

**Step 2:** Set `self.tableView.delegate = self` and `self.tableView.datasource = self`

Comment: I do follow your advice,but `numberOfRowsInSection`  still returns 0;

Comment: Then it's problem with your [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems]. Try to put break point at this method and debug. I think you are not getting allItems from this.

Comment: I find out the logic problem of my code,and I edit it and `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and returns 5,however, the new problem appears, the debug area shows this information`2016-07-25 15:11:17.348 Homepwner[19994:400896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier UITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' `

Comment: Have you registered your cell like : UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; ??? And make sure you have set cellIdentifier to cell in storyboard or programmatically.

Comment: I understand it, I use the reusablecell method and I didn't register the cell.And if I manually create the cell I don't have to register the cell class, is it right?

Comment: No. Still you will have to register the cell class so that tableView can find it.

Comment: I didn't register it when I manually created the cell and it works, if it is automatically registered when I manually created the cell?

Comment: `UITableViewCell *celll = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath: `method

Comment: Here you are using reuseIdentifier, but you have not set it anywhere so tableView is not finding the cell which have  identifier @"UITableViewCell" . So must register it then and then only you can use it.

Comment: If that solves your problem you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this in cellForRowAtIndexPath to fix the crash issue and also check that the delegate properly set or not

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"yourCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I understand it, I use the reusablecell method and I didn't register the cell.And if I manually create the cell I don't have to register the cell class, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have properly connected "Data Source" and "Delegate" of the tableview to the View Controller either from Code or from storyboard.

Comment: I do follow your advice,but `numberOfRowsInSection`  still returns 0;

Comment: Check your array  [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems]. It must return some integer and if it populates some value then I'm sure the method "cellForRowAtIndexpath" will be called.

Comment: I find out the logic problem of my code,and I edit it and `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and returns 5,however, the new problem appears, the debug area shows this information`2016-07-25 15:11:17.348 Homepwner[19994:400896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier UITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' `

Comment: Just open the storyboard and select the tableview in ViewController. Now, select the cell which you have created in it and assign the identifier in properties pane as "UITableViewCell" -- you have used in code. This will remove your error.

Comment: I didn't use Storyboard or xib.

Comment: I understand it, I use the reusablecell method and I didn't register the cell.And if I manually create the cell I don't have to register the cell class, is it right?

Comment: Yes. Your understanding is correct. You need to register the cell class if you want to dequeue cell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `numberOfRowsInSection` is not return 0;

```
- (instancetype)init{

    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if (self) {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self;
        self.tableView.delegate = self;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]createItem];
        }
    }
    return self;
    }
```

**EDIT**

write this line in `init` method.

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
```

Comment: I do follow your advice,but `numberOfRowsInSection`  still returns 0;

Comment: check your datasource [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems]

Comment: allItems you are getting 0.

Comment: I find out the logic problem of my code,and I edit it and `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and returns 5,however, the new problem appears, the debug area shows this information`2016-07-25 15:11:17.348 Homepwner[19994:400896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier UITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' `

Comment: It works and I wonder why, sorry for ask such silly question,and I just lear iOS programming by the book iOS Programming 4th Edition by Big Nerd Ranch.I follow the tutorial step by step.

Comment: I understand it, I use the reusablecell method and I didn't register the cell.And if I manually create the cell I don't have to register the cell class, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm

1. add Protocols in your `BNRItemViewcontroller` just like this : `@interface BNRItemViewcontroller() <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`
2. if you use Storyboard or xib, you should confirm dataSource & delegate with the outlets of Storyboard/xib or write `self.tableview.dataSource = self` & `self.tableview.delegate = self` instead.

Comment: I do follow your advice,but `numberOfRowsInSection`  still returns 0;

Comment: I find out the logic problem of my code,and I edit it and `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and returns 5,however, the new problem appears, the debug area shows this information`2016-07-25 15:11:17.348 Homepwner[19994:400896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier UITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' `

Comment: I understand it, I use the reusablecell method and I didn't register the cell.And if I manually create the cell I don't have to register the cell class, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways

1.Please check that you have properly connected "Data Source" and "Delegate" of tableview 
2. self.tableView.delegate = self & self.tableView.datasource = self

Comment: I find out the logic problem of my code,and I edit it and `numberOfRowsInSection` is called and returns 5,however, the new problem appears, the debug area shows this information`2016-07-25 15:11:17.348 Homepwner[19994:400896] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier UITableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' `

Comment: If you are using Storyboard then Select tableview increase tableview Prototype cell. Select cell and set cell identifier as "UITableViewCell"

Comment: I didn't use Storyboard or xib

Comment: add this code if  (UITableViewCell *cell ==nil) init tableview cell then dequee

Comment: I understand it, I use the reusablecell method and I didn't register the cell.And if I manually create the cell I don't have to register the cell class, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

There can be seven reasons:

Like in accepted answer

1. Controller needs to conform to `UITableViewDataSourceDelegate` and `UITableViewDelegate`
2. You must assign delegates `self.tableView.delegate = self` and `self.tableView.datasource = self`

Futhermore:

3. `numberOfSectionsInTableView` must return number `> 0` (`1` if you want to have one main section)
4. `numberOfRowsInSection` must return number `> 0`
5. `UITableView` needs different frame than `CGRectZero`. You should't create UITableView in that way: `self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];`
6. `heightForRowAtIndexPath` must return number `> 0`
7. Some other controller (in inheritance) can take delegate methods. Only if you have one tableView for more than one controller.